# How to modify a variable of diferent components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple react app of a counter who is added when I click a button.
I have two components: Button and Counter:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Button} from './components/button';
import {Counter} from './components/counter';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Button></Button>
        <Counter></Counter>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Button:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const Button = ({addNumber}) => {
  return (<>
    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => {
        
    }}>Click me</button>
  </>
  )
}
```

Counter:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const Counter = () => {

    let [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div id="counter">{number}</div>
  )
}
```

What thing I have to put inside the onClick of Button?
How can I change the value of a counter's variable from button component?

Comment: Lift the state up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you need to share state between two different components in React, the state must be lifted to a common, parent component. While there are other patterns that can be used in limited scenarios, lifting up state is a core concept to React and is something that will frequently occur during design and refactoring.

In your example, you can define the state in the App component like so:

```js
function App() {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);
}
```

Then you make use of that state in both components. You pass `clickCount` as a property to your `Counter` component, and remove the `Counter's` existing state. In React terms, `Counter` is now a *controlled component*. When its props update, so will the display.

```js
export const Counter = ({clickCount}) => {

  
  return (
    <div id="counter">{clickCount}</div>
  )
}
```

For your button, there are two methods you can use to have it update the count. The idiomatic way is to define your click handler in the parent `App()`, then pass it to `Button` as a property.

Alternatively, you can pass the mutator `setClickCount()` directly, but this somewhat of an anti-pattern .

```
function App() {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // this form avoids you having to access clickCount directly
    setClickCount(prevVal => prevVal++);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <Button onClick={handleClick}></Button>
        <Counter clickCount={clickCount}></Counter>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export const Button = ({handleClick}) => {
  return (<>
    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  </>
  )
}
```

Notice that after this change, the only component that has any state is `App()`. Both `Counter` and `Button` are just simple *presentational* components that can be reused elsewhere. While `App()` is now considered a *controller* and typically will only exist as a singleton.

This is a common pattern in React -- extracting state to a controller. The downside is that your controllers tend to become fairly large, often containing multiple pieces of unrelated state used by the various children.

There are a number of solutions to this problem, often called *state management strategies*. A simple one is to make use of [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) which is a different way to decouple state from the components that use it.

Comment: How can I do it? I have to create a component who includes button and counter and who manage the variables?

Comment: Yes, that is the approach

Comment: @GasparGiménez I edited my answer with an example